# css dropdown menu in navigation bar

Tags: html, css, web

I have a navigation bar with 6 elements. The first two of them have an additional dropdown menu, which should be displayed on mouse over. The problem is this menu is displayed when the mouse is over the space of the dropdown menu and not when the mouse is over the navigation bar element.

(if it's not clear you can have a look at www.buscocolegio.com and approach the mouse from bottom to top to the first two elements of the navigation bar, you will see the dropdown menu is displayed before reaching the navigation bar element)

here are the JSP and CSS I have implemented:

```
<div id="main-nav">
<ul id="navbar" class="main-nav-btn">
<li class="buscador-btn">
    <a href="#" title="Buscador Colegios, Institutos, Centros de Ense&ntilde;anza">Buscador Colegios</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/" title="Centros en territorio nacional">Espa&ntilde;a</a></li>
        <li><a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/buscador-colegios-exterior.jsp" title="Centros Espa&ntilde;oles en extranjero">Exterior</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="buscador-btn">
    <a href="#" title="Opini&oacute;n Personal de usuarios sobre Colegios">Opini&oacute;n Usuarios</a>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/Colegio/ranking-colegios.jsp" title="Ranking de Colegios por opini&oacute;n personal de usuarios">Ranking</a></li>
        <li><a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/Colegio/opiniones-comentarios-colegios.jsp" title="Comentarios, opiniones de usuarios sobre Colegios">Comentarios</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li class="criterios-btn"><a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/criterios-seleccion.html" title="Criterios de Selecci&oacute;n de Colegios">Criterios de Selecci&oacute;n</a></li>
<li class="admision-btn"><a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/Colegio/criterios-admision-comunidad.jsp" title="Criterios de Admisi&oacute;n por Comunidades">Admisi&oacute;n por Comunidades</a></li>
<li class="ayuda-btn"><a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/Colegio/ayuda-buscar-colegio.action" title="Ayuda buscar colegios">Foro</a></li>
<li class="contacto-btn"><a href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/contacto.html" title="Contacto">Contacto</a></li>
</ul>
</div><!--MAIN NAV ENDS-->
```

and CSS

```
@CHARSET "UTF-8";
#main-nav {height: 51px;width: 100%;background-color: #204865;}
.main-nav-btn { padding: 0; width: 775px;margin: 0 auto;}
.main-nav-btn li {float: left;text-align: center;line-height: 51px;margin-right: 1px;list-style-type: none;}
.main-nav-btn li a {color: #FFF;text-align: center;text-decoration: none;height: 51px;display: block;vertical-align: 30px;}
.main-nav-btn li:hover{background-position: center -51px;background-repeat: no-repeat;}
li.buscador-btn {height: 51px;width: 140px;background-image: url(../img/botones/buscador_colegios.png);background-repeat: no-repeat;}
li.buscador-exterior-btn {background-image: url(../img/botones/buscador_colegios_exterior.png);background-repeat: no-repeat;height: 51px;width: 185px;}
li.criterios-btn {background-image: url(../img/botones/criterios_btn.png);background-repeat: no-repeat;height: 51px;width: 145px;}
li.admision-btn {background-image: url(../img/botones/buscador_colegios_exterior.png);background-repeat: no-repeat;height: 51px;width: 185px;}
li.ayuda-btn, li.contacto-btn {background-image: url(../img/botones/ayuda_btn.png);background-repeat: no-repeat;height: 51px;width: 76px;}
#navbar li:hover ul, #navbar li.hover ul {display: block;position: absolute;margin: 0;padding: 0;}
#navbar li:hover li, #navbar li.hover li {float: none;}
#navbar li:hover li a, #navbar li.hover li a {background-color: #B2DFEE;border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;color: #000;width: 140px;height: 35px;text-align: left;padding-left: 5px;line-height: 35px;position: relative;z-index: 1;}
#navbar li:hover li a:hover, #navbar li.hover li a:hover {background-color: #009ACD;border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;color: #fff;}
```

Comment: Can you make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your CSS

```
.main-nav-btn li ul {
  display:none;
}
```

**[FIDDLE DEMO >>](http://jsfiddle.net/a63gL/)**

Hope it will help.

Comment: thank you, it works!!and I choose it as accepted answer beacause it involves less lines of code

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

CSS:

```
li.buscador-btn > ul{
    display:none;
}
li.buscador-btn:hover > ul{
    display:block;
}
```